Michelson interferometer fringe disappearance and reappearance
When two closely spaced wavelengths ($\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$) are used to illuminate the Michelson interferometer, then for the fringe reappearance, we consider the equation $$n \, \lambda_1=(n+1) \, \lambda_2.$$ From where do we get this equation? Is it that dark due to $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ coinciding so that fringe reappears; if that is so, why don't we consider making them coincide at the same order rather than coinciding them at $n$-th and $(n+1)$-th order?
For fringe disappearance, we consider the equation $$n \, \lambda_1= \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \, \lambda_2.$$ Could you also explain from where we obtained this equation?

i have specified it a little more please check and tell me if more changes are required.

The last equation implies that $\lambda1=\lambda2$.

Now its corrected @flippiefanus , plz tell now

When you consider the interference between to optical fields with different wavelengths, then their frequencies are also different which means that the interference patter changes with time. You can work this out by adding two such plane waves and computing the modulus square of the superposition.

but i think in  michelson interferometer individual wavelenght interfere with each other rather formation beats
